# django models that are imported at load but don't exist yet

Tags: django, migration, models

i created a new model to replace an old model existing in my code,
the old model was imported at application start (referred to at the the top level)
i replaced the call to the new model but as you can guess - i cannot run the migrations because they load the code that imports the model,
and that results in an error:

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "model" does not exist
```

i have tried to use the `SimpleLazyObject` and `Lazy` but that doesn't seem to work (the same error occurs)

did anyone encounter this problem and solve it some way?

thanks!

Comment: can you share those lines of code ? where that call is made

Comment: it's inside a class that's defined. @DaniyalSyed


`class something(models.Model):
    VALUE = lazy(newModel.get_setting(key), int)`

the get setting is a classmethod in the new model i created

Comment: Try delete migration files from the migrations folder and then run `makemigrations app_name` and `migrate`.